# Replace a specific string with another string, unless it contains a period

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I'm looking for a way to do this with `sed` or `perl`. I have files filled with strings like this:

```
0,0,0:17
1,0,0:17
0,1,0:17
0,0,1:17
1,0,1:17
```

I also have files filled with strings like this:

```
0,0,-1:17.12
1,0,-1:17.12
2,0,-1:17.12
0,1,-1:17.12
1,1,-1:17.12
```

I want to change all instances of the number `17` into `17.12`, but I don't want to accidentally change instances of `17.12` into `17.12.12`.

Any help?

Comment: You're effectively asking for a regular expression, read: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info to see available online tools that could help you rapidly test your scenario.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the scope is too narrow and will only help one person once with a specific regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 's/:17$/:17.12/' file
```

Update:

```
sed -r 's/:17([^.]|$)/:17.12/' file
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: This isn't working for me. The output remains `0,0,0:17` in the file.

Comment: Check your file for special characters: `cat -A file` Check for whitespaces or tabs after `17` in your file.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is with a Perl negative look-ahead assertion (`(?!pattern)`, see the 'perlre' man page for details):

```
perl -ple 's/\b17\b(?!\.12\b)/17.12/' file
```

Use

```
perl -i -ple ...
```

to update the file.

This will replace '17' with '17.12' anywhere in the file as long as it is not already followed by '.12'.  It may be overkill for this problem, but the technique is worth knowing.

Answer (score 0):

Given that 17 occurs at the end of a line, you can anchor your pattern there:

```
s/17$/17.12/
```